GitHub Action cache subproject build with Gradle
I'm struggling to cache Gradle between runs
I've a mono repo with a front end and a backend.

front is in React, build with NPM.

back is in Kotlin / Java / Spring Boot build with Gradle.


The mono repo structure is the following

I've a Github workflow in two phase

BUILD: checkout, build both front and back, build Docker Image, push to Azure Registry
DEPLOY: deploy ne Azure Image to an App Service

name: ci

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "release/*"

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Build frontend
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: '20.x'
          cache: 'npm'
          cache-dependency-path: | # optional
            ./frontend/package-lock.json
            ./frontend/node_modules
      - working-directory: ./frontend
        run: | 
          npm ci
          npm run build

      - name: Copy frontend to backend
        run: cp -r ./frontend/dist ./backend/src/main/resources/static
          
      - name: Build backend
        uses: actions/setup-java@v4
        with:
          distribution: 'temurin'
          java-version: '21'
          cache: 'gradle'
          cache-dependency-path: | # optional
            ./backend/.gradle*
            ./backend/.gradle/cache/*
            ./backend/**/gradle-wrapper.*
      - working-directory: ./backend
        run: ./gradlew build --no-daemon

      - name: Copy JAR to root
        run: cp ./backend/build/libs/*.jar ./app.jar

      - name: Login via Azure CLI
        uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}

      - name: Build and push image
        uses: azure/docker-login@v1
        with:
          login-server: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_LOGIN_SERVER }}
          username: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_PASSWORD }}

      - run: |
          docker build . -t ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_LOGIN_SERVER }}/my-app:${{ github.sha }}
          docker push ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_LOGIN_SERVER }}/my-app:${{ github.sha }}

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    steps:
      - name: Login via Azure CLI
        uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}

      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'my-app'
          images: '${{ secrets.REGISTRY_LOGIN_SERVER }}/my-app:${{ github.sha }}'


The backend project structure is

gradle.properties
org.gradle.caching=true

settings.gradle.kts
rootProject.name = "backend"

buildCache {
    local {
        directory = file(".gradle/cache")
    }
}

The Github logs are
2024-06-05T14:03:49.0180894Z ##[group]Run actions/setup-java@v4
2024-06-05T14:03:49.0181349Z with:
2024-06-05T14:03:49.0182061Z   distribution: temurin
2024-06-05T14:03:49.0182430Z   java-version: 21
2024-06-05T14:03:49.0182777Z   cache: gradle
2024-06-05T14:03:49.0183435Z   cache-dependency-path: ./backend/.gradle*
./backend/.gradle/cache/*
./backend/**/gradle-wrapper.*

2024-06-05T14:03:49.0184169Z   java-package: jdk
2024-06-05T14:03:49.0184636Z   check-latest: false
2024-06-05T14:03:49.0184996Z   server-id: github
2024-06-05T14:03:49.0185433Z   server-username: GITHUB_ACTOR
2024-06-05T14:03:49.0185875Z   server-password: GITHUB_TOKEN
2024-06-05T14:03:49.0186289Z   overwrite-settings: true
2024-06-05T14:03:49.0186668Z   job-status: success
2024-06-05T14:03:49.0187132Z   token: ***
2024-06-05T14:03:49.0187451Z ##[endgroup]
2024-06-05T14:03:49.2251344Z ##[group]Installed distributions
2024-06-05T14:03:49.2320995Z Resolved Java 21.0.3+9 from tool-cache
2024-06-05T14:03:49.2321976Z Setting Java 21.0.3+9 as the default
2024-06-05T14:03:49.2359263Z Creating toolchains.xml for JDK version 21 from temurin
2024-06-05T14:03:49.2573999Z Writing to /home/runner/.m2/toolchains.xml
2024-06-05T14:03:49.2575091Z 
2024-06-05T14:03:49.2577084Z Java configuration:
2024-06-05T14:03:49.2578080Z   Distribution: temurin
2024-06-05T14:03:49.2671668Z   Version: 21.0.3+9
2024-06-05T14:03:49.2672923Z   Path: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk/21.0.3-9/x64
2024-06-05T14:03:49.2673724Z 
2024-06-05T14:03:49.2674399Z ##[endgroup]
2024-06-05T14:03:49.2688642Z Creating settings.xml with server-id: github
2024-06-05T14:03:49.2689746Z Writing to /home/runner/.m2/settings.xml
2024-06-05T14:03:49.5208441Z gradle cache is not found
2024-06-05T14:03:49.5477564Z ##[group]Run ./gradlew build --no-daemon

The issue is here

With the line "2024-06-05T14:03:49.5208441Z gradle cache is not found"

I've use the Github Action sample for caching Gradle found here
I've of course see the ability to give a subfolder in the "with" part.
I've try to setup my Gradle settings correctly, but I've always as gradle cache is not found in the log
I must missing something.

Is there a reason you do not use the official GHA action from https://github.com/gradle/actions or the 3rd party one from https://github.com/burrunan/gradle-cache-action? Both do a much better job at efficient cache reuse than actions/setup-java.

So, I finally revert most on unnecessary change and it's working
The workflow is
....
      - name: Build backend
    uses: actions/setup-java@v4
    with:
      distribution: 'temurin'
      java-version: '21'
      cache: 'gradle'
  - working-directory: ./backend
    run: ./gradlew build --no-daemon   
....

gradle.properties
org.gradle.caching=true

settings.gradle.kts
rootProject.name = "backend"

